# Associate .docx with swriter.exe LibreOffice (with PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, libreoffice, openoffice, docx

I would like to associate .docx with OpenOffice

```
$extension = ".docx"
$executable = "$MyPrograms\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe"
$fileType = "docxfile"
if (Test-Path $executable) {
    $elevated = @"
        cmd /c "assoc $extension=$fileType"
        cmd /c 'ftype $fileType="$executable" "%1" "%*"'
        New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCR:\$fileType" -Name "(Default)" -Value "$fileType file" -ErrorAction Stop
"@
    Start-Process powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-Command", $elevated
    Write-Host "`'$extension`' has been associated with `'$executable`'."
} else {
    Write-Host "`'$executable`' does not exist, so no association for `'$extension`' has been created."
```

This has some problems:

- Firstly, it can't handle files with spaces, so "This File.docx" will display two error dialogues "'This' was not found", then "'File.docx' was not found", so the ftype syntax needs to correctly handle giving `swriter.exe` the full filename, how can I do that?
- Secondly, even if I use a name without spaces, "MyFile.docx", all that happens is that a console opens showing the help output of `swriter.exe` and it does not open the application, so somehow just passing a file to `swriter.exe` is not sufficient to get the program to open. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is there a reason you are writing a PowerShell script for something that can be done with 2-3 clicks with a mouse? What version of Windows are you dealing with?  What is the text evaluation of the Set-ItemProperty line when you ran it through PowerShell ISE?

Comment: yes, very much need this as it is part of a script to automate the settings that I require. Those 2-3 clicks would equate to maybe 3000-4000 clicks among the many configurations that I am applying. Associating extensions to `swriter.exe` shouldn't be this hard. `swriter.exe` does this on both Win10 and Win11. I don't use ISE as it is ancient and not very useful, but notably, the above precise syntax works perfectly for associating `.json` with VS Code Portable, `.pdf` / `.mobi` / `.epub` with SumatraPDF and many others (including for files that have spaces in them).

Comment: It's honestly easier to use the XML file for association and/or it in combination with SetFTA too that seems to work well more flexibility and large scale for thousands of machines as you are referring to. If you are a domain and have GPOs with any of the configs, it's even better. I don't use LibreOffice for this, but it should work just fine in your case without the PowerShell script to do. I always prefer PowerShell myself, but for this, I know this pain too well for very unique and various "workstation configurations"

Comment: Couldn't fit links in comment: [SetFTA](https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/), and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/export-or-import-default-application-associations?view=windows-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **LibreOffice** is installed, you should already have the *ProgID* `LibreOffice.Docx` defined under `HKCR`.

If for some reason you don't,

- `HKCR\LibreOffice.Docx\shell\open\command`

  - `"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe" -o "%1"`

---

### Pure **PowerShell** equivalent

Run from an ***Admin* PowerShell** console, this creates the same keys/entries:

```
$extension  = '.docx'
$executable = 'D:\MyPrograms\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe'
$fileType   = 'LibreOffice.Docx'
$Hive       = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes'

New-Item -Path "$HIve\$extension" -Value $fileType
New-Item -Path "$Hive\$fileType" -Value "$fileType file"
New-Item -Path "$Hive\$fileType\Shell\Open\Command" -Type ExpandString -Force -Value @"
"$executable" -o "%1" 
"@
```

**Output:**

```
>>


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes


Name                           Property
----                           --------
.docx                          (default) : LibreOffice.Docx
LibreOffice.Docx               (default) : LibreOffice.Docx file


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\LibreOffice.Docx\Shell\Open


Name                           Property
----                           --------
Command                        (default) : "D:\MyPrograms\LibreOffice\pro
                               gram\swriter.exe" -o "%1"


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I don't have `LibreOffice.Docx` defined as I'm using Libre Office in a portable fashion, installed to `D:\MyPrograms\LibreOffice`. Your syntax worked, and used that in my code from the OP. I had to tweak `"%1"` a bit to `"""%1"""` get it to handle long filename. I'll post the fully working code in an answer below for anyone with the same issue.

Comment: @YorSubs: The quote issue is problaby because you're running it through the "extra layer" of launching `cmd.exe`. I would opt for doing it all directly from an elevated **PowerShell** session/script -- Here-Strings are great for WYSIWYG ccomposition of strings with embedded quotation marks.

Comment: Have a look at how I'm doing it. I'm using a here-string as you can see. Agree that the problem is the embedded `cmd /c`, but to my knowledege there is literally no other way to do this (I would greatly appreciate seeing one, I've tried dozens of options, and this is the only one that actually and fully works).

Answer (score 0):

With @Keith Miller's answer above, I can get my original code working to associate extensions with `swriter.exe` on the fly as follows:

```
$extension = ".docx"
$executable = "D:\MyPrograms\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe"
$fileType = "docxfile"
if (Test-Path $executable) {
    $elevated = @"
        cmd /c "assoc $extension=$fileType"
        cmd /c 'ftype $fileType="$executable" -o """%1""" "%*"'
        New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCR:\$fileType" -Name "(Default)" -Value "$fileType file" -ErrorAction Stop -Force
"@
    Start-Process powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-Command", $elevated
    Write-Host "`'$extension`' has been associated with `'$executable`'."
} else {
    Write-Host "`'$executable`' does not exist, so no association for `'$extension`' has been created."
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, I advocate: Read from `HKCR` ; but when creaing/editing keys and entries, explictly specify `HKCU:\Software\Classes` or `HKLM:\Software\Classes`.

Comment: `HKCR` is an alias to `HKLM:\Software\Classes`. It's the same place (i.e. you write to HKCR, and the information appears in HKLM, as it's the same place). For sure, you don't want to write complex information there, but for something as simple as this, it's sort of irrelevant. I'll change it to `HKLM:\Software\Classes` as you suggest though, as I guess it means I don't need to mount `HKCR`.

Comment: I understand the nature of `HKCR`, hence my recommendation. I play with the registry a lot. Will edit my answer (I was cut short by  low battery) with context when I get back to my PC.